# Permission problem on using CDH6 common-hadoop dependency

Tags: cloudera, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I use the dependency in my maven project

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
       <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.0-cdh6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

, and when i excute **mvn clean install**, the problem occured: 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:3.0.0-cdh6.0.0 -> org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:3.0.0-cdh6.0.0 -> com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:4.41.1 -> net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact net.minidev:json-smart:pom:2.3-SNAPSHOT from/to dynamodb-local-oregon (https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release): **Access denied to: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release/net/minidev/json-smart/2.3-SNAPSHOT/json-smart-2.3-SNAPSHOT.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden**.

How can I solve it ?